# Different instance-method behavior between Python 2.5 and 2.6

Tags: python

Trying to change the `__unicode__` method on an instance after it's created produces different results on Python 2.5 and 2.6.

Here's a test script:

```
class Dummy(object):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'one'

    def two(self):
        return u'two'

d = Dummy()
print unicode(d)
d.__unicode__ = d.two
print unicode(d)
print d.__unicode__()
```

On Python 2.5, this produces

```
one
two
two
```

That is, changing the instance's `__unicode__` also changes `unicode(instance)`

On Python 2.6, this produces

```
one
one
two
```

So, after a change, `unicode(instance)` and `instance.__unicode__()` return different results.

Why? How can I get this working on Python 2.6?

(For what it's worth, the use case here is that I want to append something to the output of `__unicode__` for all subclasses of a given class, without having to modify the code of the subclasses.)

**Edit to make the use case a little clearer**

I have Class A, which has many subclasses. Those subclasses define simple `__unicode__` methods. I want to add logic so that, for instances of a Class A subclass, unicode(instance) gets something tacked on to the end. To keep the code simple, and because there are many subclasses I don't want to change, I'd prefer to avoid editing subclass code.

This is actually existing code that works in Python 2.5. It's something like this:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._original_unicode = self.__unicode__
        self.__unicode__ = self.augmented_unicode

    def augmented_unicode(self):
        return self._original_unicode() + u' EXTRA'
```

It's this code that no longer works on 2.6. Any suggestions on how to achieve this without modifying subclass code? (If the answer involves metaclasses, note that class A is itself a subclass of another class -- django.db.models.Model -- with a pretty elaborate metaclass.)

Comment: Looking at the Python 2.6 release notes, the item that seems like it might be causing this is a method cache on type objects --http://bugs.python.org/issue1700288 -- but if that is indeed the culprit, how do I clear the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are not allowed to [monkey-patch protocol methods](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2009_06_20.shtml) (those that begin and end with double underscores) :

> **Note**
>
> In practise there is another exception
>   that we haven't handled here. Although
>   you can override methods with instance
>   attributes (very useful for monkey
>   patching methods for test purposes)
>   you can't do this with the Python
>   protocol methods. These are the 'magic
>   methods' whose names begin and end
>   with double underscores. When invoked
>   by the Python interpreter they are
>   looked up directly on the class and
>   not on the instance (however if you
>   look them up directly - e.g.
>   x.**repr** - normal attribute lookup
>   rules apply).

That being the case, you may be stuck unless you can go with [~unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391293/different-instance-method-behavior-between-python-2-5-and-2-6/3391350#3391350).

**EDIT**: Or, you can have the base class `__unicode__` method search the instance object's dict for a `__unicode__` attribute. If it's present, then `__unicode__` is defined on the instance object, and the class method calls the instance method. Otherwise, we fall back to the class definition of `__unicode__`.

I **think** that this could allow your existing subclass code to work without any changes. However, it gets ugly if the derived class wants to invoke the class implementation -- you need to be careful to avoid infinite loops. I haven't implemented such hacks in this example; merely commented about them.

```
import types

class Dummy(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        func = self.__dict__.get("__unicode__", None)
        if func:
            // WARNING: if func() invokes this __unicode__ method directly,
            // an infinite loop could result. You may need an ugly hack to guard
            // against this. (E.g., set a flag on entry / unset the flag on exit,
            // using a try/finally to protect against exceptions.)

            return func()

        return u'one'

    def two(self):
        return u'two'

d = Dummy()
print unicode(d)
funcType = type(Dummy.__unicode__)
d.__unicode__ = types.MethodType(Dummy.two, d)
print unicode(d)
print d.__unicode__()
```

Testing with Python 2.6 produces the following output:

```
> python dummy.py 
one
two
two
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** In response to the OP's comment: Adding a layer of indirection can allow you to change the behavior of `unicode` on a per-instance basis:

```
class Dummy(object):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._unicode()

    def _unicode(self):
        return u'one'

    def two(self):
        return u'two'

d = Dummy()
print unicode(d)
# one
d._unicode = d.two
print unicode(d)
# two
print d.__unicode__()
# two
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to change the behaviour of some instances, but not of the class itself (or of all instances).

Comment: @michael you should probably subclass your special case or use some proxy with delegation. Behavior is part of the contract of a class/method and you should not change it per instance. Just wrap your instance in some other class designed with a different contract in mind.

Comment: Unfortunately the layer of indirection won't work for my particular problem, I don't think. I've updated the question to explain my use case a little more -- any suggestions for alternate approaches? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Dan is correct about monkey-patching protocol methods, and that this was a change between Python 2.5 and Python 2.6.

My fix ended up being making the change on the classes rather the instances:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.__unicode__ = self.__class__.augmented_unicode
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my solution with a possible workaround, but the implementation could get ugly if the instance method must be able to invoke the class implementation.